# Date of birth -- months only show through September

Tags: dates

Is anyone else having problems with date of birth only showing through September? I've found this on two different sites.

[image]

How would I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice of months is restricted because the date-picker does not allow future dates to be chosen for the birth date field.

1. First select a year in the past.
2. Then you will see all months available to choose.

Comment: Note: I agree this is poor usability!

Comment: Wow, somehow I'd never noticed that and when someone emailed me asking what was up with the date picker it didn't even occur to me. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have a proper solution for this? I keep getting feedback from people trying to register to an event, and cannot put their DOB correctly.
I cannot enforce the 'choose year' first on them, I need to solve this somehow technically, like defaulting the year in the date picker to a different year, but without defaulting the whole date picker value.
And ideas?